# Why is smtp.sendmail in python3 not sending the subject?

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

I have this function for send mails:

```
    def sendmail(self,ffrom,to,subject,message ="",cc = "",adj = None,msgtype = "html", codificacion='utf-8'):
        to = to.replace(" ","")
        cc = cc.replace(" ","")
        email = to
        if(cc != ""):
            email += "," + cc
        email = email.replace(" ","")

        msg = MIMEMultipart()

        msg['From'] = ffrom
        msg['To'] = to
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg['Cc'] = cc

        if(adj != None):
            for file in adj.split(","):
                file_name = file.split("/")[-1]
                part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
                fc = open(file, "rb")
                part.set_payload(fc.read())
                encoders.encode_base64(part)
                part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % (file_name))
                msg.attach(part)
                fc.close()
        t=MIMEText(message, msgtype, _charset=codificacion)
        msg.attach(t)
        #self.smtp.set_debuglevel(True)
        try: 
            #smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mi.risorse.enel:25') 
            print(msg['Subject'])
            print(msg.as_string())
            self.smtp.sendmail(msg['From'],email.split(","), msg.as_string()) 
            print ("\\nCorreo enviado\\n") 
        except: 
            print ('\nError: el mensaje no pudo enviarse. Compruebe que sendmail se encuentra instalado en su sistema\n')
```

And most of the time it works very well. However, sometimes it doesn't send the Subject.

I have printed the subject and it is there.

Comment: Have you checked the raw source of the received message to see if the subject is there?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem.

Inside the list of recipients, there was a line break (\n).

The solution was:

```
msg['To'] = to.replace(" ",'').replace("\n",'')
```

Delete the spaces and line breaks before sending the mail.